# Cannot access my django app at google cloud on port 8000

Tags: python, django, gcloud

I'm trying to run my Djnago application on google cloud by using the following command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The Application runs as normal and start receiving the sensor measurement data as the screenshot shows. However when I try to access the Django admin section by visiting http://35.237.20.70:8000/admin it does not connect and says **The Site Cannot Be Reached**. Also when I try to send data from Postman to the this  url : http://35.237.20.70:8000/api/sensordata/ for sensor measurement It also returns the same error. However on the terminal I can see the reading being recorded from the device.

[image: Screenshot of application running on gcloud.]

Comment: Do you have a firewall rule that allows incoming connections to port 8000? https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls

Comment: The sensor is able to send data so doesn't it should also work?

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see that part. Yes it should. Where is the sensor located, i.e. what  is the IP address? Are they in the same LAN?

Comment: No it's not in the same LAN, the sensor is located on a remote location, not sure what It's IP is. I'm talking with the owner and will see if adding the rules solves it. Else will ask him more info about sensor.

Comment: As is very well documented, you should **not** use runserver in production.

Comment: I believe you are referring to a Compute Engine instance, correct? If so, can you confirm the firewall rule [1] is allowing access to that port? I know the sensor is able to communicate but are you actually using the public IP for the VM instance? I tried using ping but no success, also tried scanning ports (nmap -NP) and failed.
[1] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#protocols_and_ports